# how to insert record set value in to the table?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Am having 6 fields in the record set

I want to insert into the table? How can I insert.

Used Query

```
INSERT INTO table values (recordset (0), recordset (1) ….. recordset (6))
```

But It showing Undefined function “recordset”

Please how to insert record set value in to the table?

Comment: Please give more detail of what you're trying to accomplish. What is this "record set"? Is this an ADO RecordSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
If recordSet.EOF = False Then

recordSet.MoveFirst

cmdCommand.CommandText = "insert into table ( field1) values ( " + recordSet.Fields(0) + ")"
cmdCommand.Execute()
recordSet.MoveNext
Loop Until recordSet.EOF = True
```

Keep in mind that you will need quotes in varchar fields

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `recordsetname.fields("field_name")` and check that the `recorsetname` variable was defined. You can also use the syntax `recordsetname!field_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Konstantinos gives a good answer, but you just need to be careful of the potential for SQL Injection issues.

The simplest fix would be to just replace any single apostrophes with two.

.CommandText = "insert into table (field1) values ( '" & Replace(recordSet.Fields(0), "'", "''") & "')"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're attempting to INSERT multiple records using a single statement (one INSERT for 6 records instead of 6 INSERT for 1 record each). If that's the case, the [INSERT syntax](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ia-iz_28.htm) fully supports it.

Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
    (row1, row2)
SELECT 
    value1, value2
FROM
    OtherTable
```

When you look at it like this, you can basically take any SELECT statement and put the INSERT clause on top of it. Of course, the column names need to line up correctly for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may insert data into database using the codeigniter Framework.

> **Database**
>
> Table Name  : **user**
>
> Fields Name : **name , email**

Insert a record using codeigniter:

```
//storing data **record** into an **Array**

$data(
      'name' => 'Rudra',
      'email' => 'rud.test@gmail.com',
)

//Inserting Array into Database Table Name : **user**

$this->db->insert('user',$data);
```